# javafx.fxml.LoadException: Element does not define a default property

Tags: exception, javafx, fxml, gluon

**Load Gluon layout with FXML.**

I would like to load a Layout in a little different way then this the documentation does:
https://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/5.0.1/#_layers

The difference is that I would like to load it with FXMLLoader.

My code is similar to this example:

***Class that extends MobileApplication***

```
@Override
public void init() {
    addViewFactory("VIEW", HomeViewLoader::new);
    addLayerFactory("LAYER", LayerLoader::new);
}
```

***Class LayerLoader extends Layer*** - I would like to use this class to load the FXML

```
public LayerLoader(){

    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(fxmlPath));

    Parent root = null;
    try {
        root = loader.load();    //exception in this line
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

*Note: "View" is loaded in a similar way. And it's fine.*

***The FXML file***

```
<imports...>

<SidePopupView fx:id="sidePopup" side="LEFT" styleClass="mainFxmlClass" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.40"
xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="x.y.controller.layoutController">
    <StackPane fx:id="stackPane" prefHeight="150.0" prefWidth="200.0">
      <children>
        <Button />
      </children>
    </StackPane>  <!-- Exception in this line -->
</SidePopupView>
```

I trigger my layer to show up like this in **HomeViewLoader** class:

```
@Override
protected void updateAppBar(AppBar appBar) {
    appBar.setNavIcon(MaterialDesignIcon.MENU.button(
            e -> MobileApplication.getInstance().showLayer("LAYER"))
    );
}
```

The exception happens when I try to load the fxml in LayerLoader. It refers to my FXML.

It says that StackPane not defines a default property. (javafx.fxml.LoadException: Element does not define a default property.)

Thank you,

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Comment: Not sure, if `SidePopupView` annotates it's constructor parameter with `@NamedArg`, but the class does not seem to be annotated with `@DefaultProperty` requiring you to either wrap the `<StackPane>` element in a `<content>` elment or making it impossible to create an instance via fxml.

Comment: The error is probably referring to `SlidePopupView`. Is that your class? Can you show it?

Comment: @Slaw It is not my class, it is a Gluon class.

Comment: @fabian was right, it requires a `@NamedArg` parameter. Unfortunately, I was not aware of what are `NamedArgs` and how to use them. But I acted according to what he said and it works now.